# TouchDown only seems to fire once in the entire application [libGDX]

Tags: libgdx

So in my game I spawn a grapple hook when I touch the screen, connecting player and ceiling. The problem is that the touchDown() of my inputAdapter only seems to activate the first time I touch, nothing happens after when I touch again (meaning: no other "grapple hooks" get created, just the one). touchUp() or every other input method still work.

Here are all the classes: [Rope](http://pastebin.com/pHgRTq0v)  - [GamePlay](http://pastebin.com/SiL0ZAqJ) - [InputManager](http://pastebin.com/GNDbAG7A) and also just in case [MainMenu](http://pastebin.com/fKLE4kvn)

**EDIT**
**So I was being a moron and in the overlapsOnX() method forgot to add and substract the width of the "cloud" so unless I got very lucky (or spawned in the right place) the rope wouldnt get created.**

Here's how the method should look like

```
private boolean overlapsOnX(Body player, Body cloud){ //check if the player is currently in the same X position than a cloud
    return player.getPosition().x >= cloud.getPosition().x - (20 / PPM) && player.getPosition().x <= cloud.getPosition().x + (20 / PPM);
}
```

Comment: just move  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){ ... to the show method, and make both touchDown and touchUp methods return true.

Comment: Didnt fix it. I had it like that originally.

Comment: it could be your game logic, but never create instances inside the render loop, you are creating a new inputAdapter every frame and assigning it to the gdx inputprocessor..

Comment: Yeah I figured it was bad, still good to know thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TouchDown returns a boolean to indicate if the input has been processed or not.  You are returning false, but you probably mean to return true.  This would indicate the input has finished being handled.

Comment: Yeah I had it as true and changed it to se if it got fixed somehow. Conclusion: neither true nor false makes it work.

Comment: I'm not sure what is breaking it, but there are a few things you'll want to do: 
1.most or all of your onShow code would probably be better in the onCreate method, which gets called once when the screen is created.  
2.You should set the input processor in onCreate, not in render.  You are needlessly creating a new input processor every render loop.  This could be part of the issue.  
3.  I'm not familiar with how rope's work, but it is likely that they must be added and removed from the world at a time when the world is not mid-step.  This might be handled in the class, or maybe not.

Comment: Hey, so I tried cleaning up stuff, moving input to another class and moving stuff to the GamePlay constructor instead of show(). Everything is exactly the same though.  Here are all the classes: [Rope](http://pastebin.com/pHgRTq0v)  - [GamePlay](http://pastebin.com/SiL0ZAqJ) - [InputManager](http://pastebin.com/GNDbAG7A) and also just in case [MainMenu](http://pastebin.com/fKLE4kvn)

Comment: Try printing something at the start of touch down, to be sure if it is/isn't being called.  I notice you check if the world is locked, which probably prevents the game from crashing, but in the case that it is locked the code will just skip past the actual joint initialization.  You could of course put this in a while loop, or probably preferably from a performance standpoint, just set a boolean toCreate = true in the Rope class when touchdown occurs, and then create the rope and set it to false in an update() method in Rope which you call once per render cycle, before stepping the world.

Comment: Its fixed now, I just skipped a little deatil in a method. I edited the OP. I'll make and effort to be more careful before posting here in the future. Thanks for all the tips though!